# Discrete measures and discrete kernels

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

This question was also posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194506/discrete-measures-and-discrete-kernels). Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\mu$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$ defined by $\mu=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\delta_{x_k}$ for some sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R^d,$ where we denote by $\delta_x$ the point measure at $x.$ For each $x\in\text{supp}\mu$ assume we are given a sequence $(y_l(x))_{l\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and define a probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$ by $K(x,\cdot):=\sum_{l=1}^\infty 2^{-l}\delta_{y_l(x)}(\cdot).$ My question is, does $K$ define a probability kernel, i.e. is $K$ measurable w.r.t. $x$? If this is true, then we can define a probability measure on $\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d$ by $$(\mu\otimes K)(B)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}1_B(x,y)K(x,dy)\mu(dx),$$
for $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d).$ But is it clear that the resulting measure is still discrete?